# Prove a goal with an assumption in HOL

Tags: theorem-proving, hol

I state the following goal in HOL4:

```
set_goal([``A:bool``,``B:bool``], ``B:bool``);
```

resulting in the proof state

```
val it =
   Proof manager status: 1 proof.
   1. Incomplete goalstack:
    Initial goal:

    B
    ------------------------------------
      0.  B
      1.  A

   : proofs
```

I tried to find a proper tactic for using the assumptions. I came up with `ASM_MESON_TAC`:

```
e (mesonLib.ASM_MESON_TAC [])
```

and it proved the goal:

```
OK..
Meson search level: ..
val it =
   Initial goal proved.
    [..] ⊢ B: proof
```

Is this the standard tactic in such a situation? Or, is there a simpler one?

Answer (score 2):

```
e (FIRST_ASSUM ACCEPT_TAC)
```

does it.

`FIRST_ASSUM` applies the argument theorem tactic on assumptions until success.

`ACCEPT_TAC` simply proves a goal if we supply the same theorem.

```
ACCEPT_TAC: thm -> tactic
FIRST_ASSUM: (thm -> tactic) -> tactic
```

(thanks to somebody on #hol)